# Flag dialog box should show the contents of the custom flag raised earlier

Tags: feature-request, flags

The appearance of the flag dialog box after a custom flag was raised:

[image]

The custom flag box tells me "This is the flag you currently have raised". While this is *technically* correct, it isn't very useful because it doesn't tell me exactly what my flag contents were i.e. what exact message I had written for the moderators.

I have to look up the `users/flag-summary` page, scroll down to the specific URL, and then see what my message was. This isn't a terribly bad problem, but I don't think it's really hard to include my custom flag text in the flag dialog itself. So, I think this can be considered for implementation.

Comment: *"This isn't a terribly bad problem"* - Heh.  When you have thousands of flags, like @starball (offering a bounty on this currently) and me, finding the text of the flag in 40 (currently) pages can take a while ;-)

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Related: [Add a filter for custom flags in your flag history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358961/add-a-filter-for-custom-flags-in-your-flag-history)

Comment: A broader request: [When flagging, could we see any previous flags (including already-handled ones) we've raised on the same post?](/q/212784/997587)

Comment: this would also make it easier to [effectively edit custom mod flags](/q/96026/997587), which currently, I have to dig through my numerous flag pages to find the previous flag message I used.