# Add a filter for custom flags in your flag history

Tags: feature-request, flags, flag-history

In my [flag history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/current), there is no filter to view only the "in need of moderator intervention" flags you've raised.  I went to find a specific custom flag that had been declined to review it, and possibly avoid making the same mistake that caused the flag to be declined, and had to search through many more pages than I would have if I had just clicked `Mod flags --> declined/helpful`.  I could also use this filter to mention certain mod flags that had been used for some purpose.

Can we add a filter to view only custom flags?

Comment: And "post flags" doesn't help, because the mod flags are buried in VLQ/NAA flags...

Comment: @Makyen I meant the "In need of mod intervention" flags, which should be as important as the red ones.  I'll fix the post.